# VBA: add char to a column and resize the range

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro to hopefully copy the values in cells A1,A2, A3, A4, A5, A6...to columns C1, D1, E1, C2, D2,E2...respectively.
I also want to add characters before and after each copied cell.
This is what I currently got after reading 
[How to add text to the beginning or end of all cells in Excel?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/670-excel-add-text-to-beginning-end-of-cell.html) and some other websites.

```
Sub reformat()
Dim c As Range
dim destination As Range
Set destination=Range("C1")
Set destination=destination.Resize(3,33)
For Each c In Selection
If c.Value<>" " Then destination.Value="beginning"&c.Value&"ending"
Next
End Sub
```

This gives the following error message `run-time error'91':object variable or with block variable not set` for line `If c.Value<>" " Then`.  My biggest problem is figuring out how to copy values to the specified area which has more columns.

---

Update: 
Thanks to Stefan's advise, I have changed my code to the following:

```
Sub reformat()
Dim c As Range
dim destination As Range
Set destination=Range("C1")
destination=destination.Resize(3,33)
For Each c In Selection
If c.Value<>" " Then destination.Value="beginning"&c.Value&"ending"
Next
End Sub
```

Now the old problem no longer appears but only cell C1 is filled.

Comment: I can't replicate this.  What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Your destination does not change. Consider using `destination.offset(rowindex).value=something` then increment `rowindex`

Comment: The error comes for `If c.Value<>" "` @Comintern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will copy the selected values into a 3-column matrix, upper left corner in [M1]:

```
Sub reformat()
' copy cell values from selection into 3-column wide destination
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473802/vba-add-char-to-a-column-and-resize-the-range#34473802
' 2015-12-26
    Dim c As Range, destination As Range
    Dim ct As Long

    ct = Selection.Cells.Count
    Set destination = Range("M1").Resize(CInt((ct + 1) / 3), 3)
    ct = 0
    For Each c In Selection
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            destination(CInt(ct \ 3) + 1, (ct Mod 3) + 1).Value = "beginning" & c.Value & "ending"
            ct = ct + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
Set destination=Range("C1") 
Set destination=destination.Resize(3,33)
```

you should should only use `set` one time to initialize the `destination` object.

I guess you should just say

```
destination.resize(3,33)
```

Edit

```
Dim c As Range
dim destination As Range
Set destination=Range("C1")
destination.Resize(3,33)
I=0
For Each c In Selection
   If c.Value<>"" Then    
      destination.offset(i).Value="beginning"&c.Value&"ending"
   Endif
   I=i+1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed but there is still same error message for  line`If c.Value<>" "`

Comment: Did you select A1 to A6 before running the macro? You could replace `Selection` with `Range("A1:A6")` if it's always this range.

Comment: Also, you probably should remove the space in `if c.value<>" "`

Comment: Yes, I selected. I fixed a typo and now the previous error message no longer appears, but the problem is that only cell C1 is filled

Comment: See my comment  to your question, about `.offset`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim c As Range
    Dim destination As Range
    Set destination = Range("C1")

    i = 0
    For Each c In Selection
       If c.Value <> " " Then
          destination.Offset(i \ 3, i Mod 3).Value = "beginning" & c.Value & "ending"
       End If
       i = i + 1

Next
```